# Formik & Yup - How to make a schema for an array and string

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using `Formik` to create a form of a book library where each item in the list would look like:

```
author: {
 name: 'string',
 titles: ['string']
}
```

I am having trouble trying to make a schema with `Yup` to validate those fields. I have:

```
schema = Yup.object().shape({
 author: Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().min().max().required('...')
 }),
 author: Yup.array().of(
  Yup.object().shape({
   titles: Yup.string().min().max().required('...')
  })
 )
});
```

The initial values are also:

```
{
 author: {name: ''},
 author: [{ titles: '' }]
}
```

My validation works for the array but not the name. I am assuming the issue is that I cannot have the same name for both of the elements in the object, however I do not know how to combine the two fields in both the initial values as well as the schema. I looked through Yup API and I noticed they had `mixed()` but I didn't understand how to implement with what I need. Is this way possible or would having validation for both of these possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author is not an array, it's an object which contains an array and a string. Also, you're defining it twice:

```
schema = Yup.object().shape({
 author: Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().min().max().required('...'),
  titles: Yup.arrayOf(Yup.string())
 }),
});
```

Confused about why you have 2 author keys. The schema above corresponds to:

```
{
  author: {
    name: "hehyryg",
    titles: ["title", "title2"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I was playing around with the schema order and that was what I left it as since I couldn't figure out the proper order